# F# Main argv and if statement confusion

Tags: f#

What is the purpose of `EntryPoint`?
How do I pass a variable into `argv` to allow it to print out "Hello variable" instead of receiving the default not enough arguments?

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    if argv.Length >= 1
        then printfn "Hello %s" argv.[0]; 0
        else printfn "Not enough arguments"; 1
```

Comment: `argv` contain the command line arguments so you provide them when you run the program e.g. `MyProgram.exe variable`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`[EntryPointAttribute]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.entrypointattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) is the first function to be called when you run your application:

> Adding this attribute to a function indicates it is the entry point
>   for an application. If this absent is not specified for an EXE then
>   the initialization implicit in the module bindings in the last file in
>   the compilation sequence are used as the entry point.

To pass values whilst debugging you can setup some arguments in the Project Properties (assuming you're using Visual Studio).

Goto **Project** menu, and select **MyProject Properties...**, then select the **Debug** page from the left hand side and you can enter your arguments there:

[image: Project Properties, Debug]

If you're not using Visual Studio, then there should be a way to do it too, consult their documentation, or update your question.

If you are running outside of the debugger, you need a cmd window and then just pass them:

```
> MyProject.exe /Arg1
```

Comment: Yeah I was using Visual Studio, thank's for the quick reply.
It was frustrating me :)

Comment: I am not really sure what is the benefit of this Attribute. If there are any functions after `main` , how would I even be able to use them?

Comment: @asibahi a program has to start *somewhere* when you run it from the command line. There may be many classes with a `main` method. As for other functions - just call them from your entry function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos none of the other functions would be *after* the `main` function in the code, due to F#'s compilation order. Why do you need an attribute to begin with when being the last function in the last file should be sufficient?

Comment: Why should it be the last one?? What about assembly references? In any case, the order is lost as soon as the compiler generates IL. At that level, the attribute is what tells the runtime where to start execution

Comment: This attribute is basically the F# equivalent of setting the `StartupObject` project property of a C# application. It is mandatory because F# tends to agree more frequently than C# with Python's tenet that "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not sure you understand what I'm trying to say. I'm referring to this snippet in the answer "Adding this attribute to a function indicates it is the entry point for an application. If this absent is not specified for an EXE then the initialization implicit in the module bindings in the last file in the compilation sequence are used as the entry point." What is the plausible scenario for an EXE to have functions defined after the 'main' function. When the F# compiler can't reference these functions from 'main'. IL has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it should be the last one because that's how the F# compiler works.

Comment: Last of which? The main assembly or the referenced ones? Even a .exe can be referenced as an assembly. The compiler can't say "*I'll just pick the last method in every `exe` project in the solution and mark it as `EntryPoint`, even if it doesn't take any arguments*"